# How to pass data from Afragment to Bactivity on xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Afragment.cs

```html
var data=new Intent(this,typeof(Bactivity));
    data.PutStringArrayListExtra("ByGenres",TrackModel.Track);
        data.PutExtra("position",e.Position);
        StartActivity(data);
```

> - Error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected
> - Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Android.Content.Intent.Intent(Android.Content.Context, System.Type)'
>     has some invalid arguments (CS1502)

Can't pass data to Bacitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fragment you have to use `Activity` instead of `this` `var data=new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(Bactivity));`

```
var str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); 
... 
T obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
```

If it is a large object the latter is better as it is much faster.

Use the serialize function to convert the object to string and on the activity use deserialize to convert back into object.

```
var track=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items.tracks); 
var data=new Intent(this.Activity,typeof(AudioPlayer)); 
data.PutExtra("listdata",track);
data.PutExtra("position",e.Position);
StartActivity(data);
```

Comment: sr. I got problem at PutStringArrayListExtra.

Comment: No. cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<TrackModel.Track>' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' (CS1503)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110455/discussion-between-akshay-kulkarni-and-j-joe).